# twython get api error code

Tags: python, twitter, exception, twython

I am trying to get the exception code from Twitter API (using **twython**), but it returns an HTTP error code instead.

[Here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/response-codes.html) you can see the codes from twitter API.

For example:

```
try:
    twitter.retweet(id=tweet["id"])      
except TwythonError as e:     
    print("FAILED to retweet: [tweet_id:" + str(tweet["id"]) + "]")
    print(e.error_code)
```

The following prints HTTP error code instead of twitter API code

```
print(e.error_code)
```

For example instead of API error code **261** or **271**, **272**,...  it prints HTTP error **403** (Forbidden).

This is a problem because I cannot distinguish between codes that share the same HTTP error code.

Answer (score 0):

If you print out all of e with `print(e)`, you will get additional information.

Comment: I know. But I want to get the api error code, so that I can handle the error depending on that, with code. I don't want to just print the string of the error that explains the error.